# I want to Add a prefix on all website href links

Tags: java, javascript

I want to Add a prefix on all website href links For Example -i want to add a prefix - xyz.com/url? on all links - Suppose a href link is the url is - fpqr.com .After adding that prefix its shows - http://www.xyz.com/url?http://www.fpqr.com

Comment: Note the difference between `attr` and `prop`. With `attr` You'll get the original `href` value from the links, relative links in cases whereas with `prop` you'll get the value that the 'final' link would be. Make sure to choose appropriately for your needs

Comment: Was there more to this question originally? People below seem to know what you're talking about, yet it's currently so unclear it's utterly worthless. Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages. Which are you actually using? Which of the two domains (xyz or fpqr) is yours? Do you want to replace links at the client side, such as in a page that's open in the browser, or in HTML in strings? Or at the server side, in HTML as it's generated, or to redirect links when requested? Or are you doing a search & replace in files on disk? Or writing a proxy to hijack links on the wire?

Answer (score 3):

I have written this code:

```
var prefix = "http://www.xyz.com/url?";
$('a').each(function(){
    var currentHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href',prefix+currentHref);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joeSaad/zLSx3/#base

Answer (score 1):

Using `jQuery` something like this should do the trick:

```
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('href', 'http://prefix.com/?x=' + $(this).prop('href'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Such url rewriting should be handled at the web server level only.

Here is what you have to do within httpd.conf if your web server is apache.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.fpqr\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.xyz.com/url/%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var prefix = 'prefix';
 $('a').attr('href', prefix +$('a').attr('href'));
```

Hope this helps a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a (live) links collection that contains all links in a page, so you can easily access all the links in a page and modify their href like:

```
var links = document.links;
for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  // use of \/\/ is to avoid SO posting rules
  links[i].href = 'http:\/\/xyz.com/url?' + links[i].href;
}
```

Note that not all A elements are links, they can be anchors (i.e. have a name or ID and not have an href property). Adding an href will change anchors to links, maybe not what you want to do.